# Solving power series equations arond regular singular points

Tags: power-series

Find two linearly independent series solutions to $$2xy''+y'+xy=0$$ ($x_0$ is a regular singular point),
 **Edit**
So, $$y=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nx^{n+r}$$$$y'=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+r)a_nx^{n+r-1}$$ and $$y''=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+r)(n+r-1)a_nx^{n+r-2}$$ 
 So sum works out to; $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}2(n+r)(n+r-1)a_nx^{n+r-1}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+r)a_nx^{n+r-1}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nx^{n+r+1}$$ $$=$$ $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}2(n+r)(n+r-1)a_nx^{n+r-1}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+r)a_nx^{n+r-1}+\sum^\infty_{n=2}a_{n-2}x^{n+r-1}$$ Equating coeffiecents, when $n=0$, $$2r(r-1)+r=0$$  $$r=0, r=\frac{1}{2}$$ When $n=1$ $a_1=0$ for $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_1$ is $0$ for $r=0$ Since $ a_1$ is equal to zero, then there are no odd term in the series. I then got $ a_n = \frac {a_02^{\frac {n}{2}}(-1)^n}{(2n+1)! (2n)!}$  But I can't think of a what I'd do next...

### **Edit**

i've answered the qs

Comment: I think it is "natural" to do $\;n=0\;$ in the derivatives of the series: it is not a *mere* power series but rather the variable's exponent is $\;n+r\;$ ...! If it were $\;n\;$ then yes: it is pointless to begin at $\;n=0\;$ in the derivative as that'd equal zero.

Comment: @DonAntonio. May be pointless but, from my point of view, very useful since making my life easier when playing with the same powers of $x$.

Comment: @Am  I think you may have some mistake in your differential equation (2nd. line), as you seem to have done something different when writing it with series.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I really don't think it makes life easier in general, but if that helps you then why not?

Comment: @DonAntonio. This is exactly what I was meaning ! But, remembering my old times, this is also what we learnt (at that time) in France.

Comment: @Am Shouldn't the differential equation be equal to zero, for example?

Comment: @DonAntonio. Oh, i see, thanks for clearing that up. When i made $n=0$ i got a somewhat different answer....  In the 2nd line? Do you mean that its $n+r-1$ and not $n+r-2$??

Comment: @DonAntonio yh, its equal to 0 i just forgot to put it in

Comment: @AmM Not only that: the diff. eq. seems to be $\;2xy''+y'+xy=0\;$ , and you wrote $\;...+ x\color{red}{y'}=0\;$ there

Comment: @DonAntonio oooh, that was a mistake as well haha, i'll edit that now, thanks!